# Easy Data Source Removal

Tags: python, arcpy

I am trying to remove anything in a map that has "DI" in the source path.

I have a test mxd with one df and 2 lyr's. The lyr data sources are:

> C:\Users\Corey.Fields\Python\Testing\DI_Remove\Fake_DI_Wells.shp
>   S:\Departments\GIS\ARCUSERS\PERSONAL_FOLDERS\CFields\Test.gdb\Fake_DI_Test

My code is:

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("C:\Users\Corey.Fields\Python\Testing\DI_Remove\Untitled.mxd")
for df in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd):
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df):
        if lyr.dataSource == "*DI*":
            arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, lyr)
mxd.save()
del mxd
```

The script is running but not removing the layers.

What do I have wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to evaluate whether "DI" is in the data source.

```
if "DI" in lyr.dataSource:
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use "*", rather use .find method to evaluate:

```
for df in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd):
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df):
        found = lyr.dataSource.find('DI')
        if found >-1:
            arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, lyr)
```